# Windows Service as host for WCF services - dependency injection strategy

Tags: .net, wcf, dependency-injection, windows-services, ninject

I'm writing a windows service that hosts a bunch of WCF services. I'm using NINJECT to get to AOP going with interceptors which works fine. I'm just wondering whether my implementation will hold under higher loads. Here's the thing:

In my program.Main() method:

```
ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = { kernel.Get<WcfServiceHostService>() };
ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
```

And there's the WcfServiceHostService constructor that takes to interfaces which are injected:

```
public WcfServiceHostService(IVakService vakService, IRoosterService roosterService) : this()
{
var serviceList = new List<ServiceHost> { new ServiceHost(vakService), new ServiceHost(roosterService) };
this.Services = serviceList;
}
```

The thing is - ServiceHost constructor method can be used as a generic new ServiceHost or like new ServiceHost(SingletonInstance) ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx ) - my question: by providing the instance, rather than the type, thereby forcing the interface implementation to be a singleton - aren't I negatively impacting the performance?

P.S. Isn't IIS a FAR better option to host WCF services?

Answer (score 0):

I've hosted 100+ WCF services in a Windows Service in a production environment without problems. Compared to IIS deployment is a lot easier. Of course IIS offers features such as on demand loading and process recycling as described [here](http://www.binaryfunctions.com/post/2012/12/09/An-important-difference-between-WCF-hosting-in-IIS-and-hosing-in-Windows-Service.aspx)

As for Singleton or not, I think [this page](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-wcf/0596526997/instance-management/orm9780596526993-chp-4-sect-4) has a good answer and as always it depends on what you want to achieve:

> *"The singleton service is the sworn enemy of scalability. The problem is that when multiple clients connect to the singleton, they may all do so concurrently [...]. The singleton must synchronize access to its state to avoid state corruption. [...] This may degrade throughput, responsiveness, and availability"*